# What is the correct way skip to prev/next method/function definition?

Tags: key-bindings, motion

I do not want an answer about something like Imenu or tags - features that suppose you know some keywords about the method/function name to move to.

What I want is just general commands which jump forward to next or jumps backward to previous method, e.g. in ruby-mode or emacs-lisp-mode.

Answer (score 11):

Use **`C-M-a`** (`beginning-of-defun`) to move backward before each "defun" (top-level sexp).

Use **`C-M-e`** (`end-of-defun`) to move forward after each "defun".

To move across several by repeating, just hold down Control, Alt (Meta), and `a` or `e`.

To move forward/backward `N` defuns, use a numeric prefix arg.  E.g. `C-u 1 0 C-M-e` moves forward 10 defuns.

(There are several pairs of commands that end in `a` or `e`, for moving to the beginning or end of things. The most commonly used are probably `C-a` and `C-e`.)

Comment: Is there a mnemonic that makes this memorable? e for end (-of-defun) makes sense, but then a doesn't associate with beginning. They're not adjacent on the keyboard either, or even in line with each other, in order to have a forward/back or up/down association with each other. :(

Comment: @Ben: In Emacs `a` and `e` often stand for beginning and end, respectively. Not sure what mnemonic might be helpful for thinking of `a`. But at least it's conventional in Emacs. See also `b` and `f` (back, forward) and `p` and `n` (previous, next).

Comment: Ah thanks, I hadn't noticed that pattern yet.

Comment: @Drew @Ben `a` is the *first* character in the alphabet :) It's also used e.g. in regular expressions where `\A` matches at the start of the subject (with `\z` matching at the end but let's not go there)